# Firefox addon-SDK addon not writing files (but works in jpm)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm scratching my head here...

I wrote an sdk addon that uses `OS.File` to write a text file.

It works fine using `jpm run`

However, when I install it into Firefox as an xpi

Then even my console log messages don't show up in the console.

But it still runs, I can debug it (it has a timer loop and so I see it pause on the timer when I set a breakpoint in there)

The code seems to run fine except for:

- the console log messages not being displayed
- the file not being written

What I mean by code running "fine" is the variables all seem to get filled correctly in the debugger and the execution seems to occur correctly (breakpoints work)

My extension doesn't make any visual modifications to the page. So I don't know if that part would work correctly or not, but I'm just concerned right now about the failure to log and to write files.

anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

> Then even my console log messages don't show up in the console.

jpm run sets different log levels compared to a regular firefox profile. [relevant docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/console#Logging_Levels)

> the file not being written

depending on where you do your calls to OS.File e10s may make a difference due to content sandboxing. Try toggling that. If it does make a difference then you're using file IO in a context where you shouldn't.

Comment: is there a flag to disable this kind of sandboxing? I want to write to a subfolder of the user directory. I don't want to submit this to market, just use this addon for personal use in my installation of firefox